# Convergence interval power series function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$$
a power series with $a_{n}>0,\forall n\geq0$. Calling $R$ its convergence radius, then is true (or not) that the series cannot converge in the interval
$$(-R,R]?$$

For me, it can converge, but I really don't know to show it. I don't know if there's something to do about $a_{n}>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$|a_n(-R)^n|=a_nR^n$$

thus, if $ \sum a_nR^n $ converge, it will be the same for $ \sum a_n(-R)^n$.

the converse is not true.

take $a_n=\frac 1n$.

the radius is $R=1$.

$$\sum a_nR^n=\sum \frac 1n \text{ diverge}$$
and
$$\sum a_n(-R)^n=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\text{ converge}$$